# Is the post credits scene of At World's End canon?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales, at-worlds-end

Inspired by my other question:
[Did Will neglect his duty of ferrying the dead?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160222/did-will-neglect-his-duty-of-ferrying-the-dead)

As the other question says, Will is

> cursed in that film (At World's End)

But the post-credits scene says Will did return 10 years later to Elizabeth and their son. But in **Dead Men Tell No Tales** / (also titled **Salazar's Revenge** in some countries)

> Henry, Wills son sees Will cursed when he was still as a child. Then nine years later from that - the plot of the movie happens. There would be no time for the post-credits scene where Will is normal.

Is the scene canon or am I misunderstanding the timeline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script to [At World's End](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/a2/pirates--of-the-caribbean-worlds-end-script.html) indicates that the curse allows for one day ashore every 10 years:

Regarding Jones:

> And every ten years...
>
> ...him could come ashore...
>
> ...to be with she who love him... truly.

Later in regard to Will:

> This ship has a purpose again.
>
> And where we are bound...
>
> ...she cannot come.
>
> One day ashore.
>
> Ten years at sea.
>
> That's a steep price for what's been done.
>
> Depends on the one day.

Comment: "Depends on the one day." An entire novel of love and beauty in a single sentence.

Comment: Wasn't it in the script (but not actually in the movie) that the curse is lifted if the love stays true for the whole decade apart? At work so can't source but know I heard that somewhere

Comment: So in short, I had the timeline wrong in my head.